# Are true drake powers active in both in natural and drake form?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, shadowrun

True drakes have a few additional powers they can get like magical guard and dragonspeech.
Are these also active only in their drake form or are these active also in their metahuman form?

Comment: Are you looking for just RAW answers or would house rules be okay?

Comment: Mostly RAW, but if there is no real RAW way there also looking for typically used houserules (if they are marked as thus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since true drakes are dracoforms that assume a metahuman form, I would assume that they use the *Shift (Human)* ability associated with shapeshifters found in the *Runner's Companion*. (In contrast drake's are metahumans that assume a dracoform using *Shift (Drake)*)

> **Shift (Human)** 
>   A shapeshifter can only assume a single, specific human form,
>   chosen at character creation. This form is the same gender as the
>   animal, and generally shares other traits as well—eyes of the same
>   color, hair similar to the animal’s fur or plumage, distinctive scars
>   and injuries, tattoos, etc. The human form’s apparent ethnicity is
>   often (but not always), similar to that of humans residing in its
>   native area and possesses unique fingerprints and retinas which
>   are consistent from transformation to transformation. Samples of
>   tissue taken from the human form will show animal, not human,
>   DNA and can serve as material links (see Material Links, p. 28,
>   Street Magic) to the character regardless of current form.
>   **Shapeshifters retain all of their powers and weaknesses in
>   shifted human form except for their Natural Weapon.** (Source: *Runner's Companion* pg.88, emphasis mine)

Since I can't find any specific ruling within the text for true drake characters (*The Clutch of Dragons*, pg.137) then I would assume the general ruling found here applies. (And, in any case, why would a run-of-the mill shapeshifter be the more powerful of the two and retain all of it's powers in metahuman form while the true drake does not?)